# How to connect SAP BOBJ to Microsoft SQL Server 2012 using ODBC?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, business-objects

I have a requirement to create a connection between BOBJ and Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Can someone tell me the detailed steps on how to do that?

I found that I need to edit an `odbc.ini` file to add the details of the SQL Server like hostname, database name, driver etc.

Also where can I get the driver to connect to SQL Server? Does it come in the system itself?

Comment: Are you on the SQL Server? ODBC drivers can be found (for 64 bit) by typing ODBCAD32.EXE into the Start>Search window. For 32 bit they are under C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ODBCAD32.exe  

If you click on System DSN and then Add... you should find the SQL Native Client (or ODBC Driver XX for SQL Server).

Comment: BOBJ is installed on linux redhat, and I need to create a relational connection using odbc to Microsoft SQL server 2012. Do I need to download the driver from somewhere and configure them?

Answer (score 0):

There are free [DataDirect ODBC drivers for SQL Server on Linux](https://www.progress.com/odbc/microsoft-sql-server) distributed with BOBJ Data Services: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/EIM/To+configure+DataDirect+ODBC+on+Linux+and+Unix

Comment: As stated on the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) please quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.